# Side-by-Side threeparttable?

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I have an minor issue in which I have two threeparttables that are small enough to fit onto one landscape page, but I can't figure out how to get them to be side by side.  Including two threeparttable environments inside the table environment only puts them above and below each other (for me at least).

Any suggestions? I posted the tables below. Sorry they're not simpler, but I wanted to include everything that I'm working with (in case it's some other package I'm using that's causing the problem.)

```
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multicolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] 
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Variance Decomposition: 1915--1963$^a$}

\label{VarDecomp}

\begin{tabular}{c | D{.}{.}{1.2} D{.}{.}{2.2} D{.}{.}{1.2} | D{.}{.}{1.2} D{.}{.}{2.2} D{.}{.}{2.2} }

\hline \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Period} & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{Output Growth} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Deficit Ratio} \\
&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{${\varepsilon_\tau}^b$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\varepsilon_y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c |}{$\varepsilon_g$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{${\varepsilon_\tau}^b$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\varepsilon_y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\varepsilon_g$} \\ \hline

1 & 3.13 & 89.86 & 7.01 & 0.99 & 24.41 & 74.60 \\

2 & 2.04 & 88.74 & 9.22 & 1.05 & 29.32 & 69.63 \\

3 & 1.45 & 94.10 & 4.45 & 0.98 & 35.78 & 63.24 \\

4 & 1.64 & 98.15 & 0.21 & 0.98 & 39.97 & 59.06 \\

5 & 2.25 & 96.10 & 1.65 & 1.04 & 42.31 & 56.65 \\ \hline

6 & 2.92 & 89.87 & 7.21 & 1.16 & 43.50 & 55.34 \\

7 & 3.40 & 84.91 & 11.69 & 1.31 & 43.82 & 54.87 \\

8 & 3.64 & 84.18 & 12.18 & 1.46 & 43.52 & 55.02 \\

9 & 3.68 & 86.36 & 9.96 & 1.56 & 42.92 & 55.52 \\

10 & 3.60 & 89.09 & 7.30 & 1.61 & 42.31 & 56.08 \\ \hline

11 & 3.49 & 91.13 & 5.38 & 1.59 & 41.87 & 56.53 \\

12 & 3.39 & 92.28 & 4.33 & 1.55 & 41.65 & 56.80 \\

13 & 3.34 & 92.75 & 3.91 & 1.50 & 41.61 & 56.89 \\

14 & 3.34 & 92.78 & 3.88 & 1.46 & 41.67 & 56.87 \\

15 & 3.38 & 92.55 & 4.07 & 1.44 & 41.76 & 56.80 \\ \hline

16 & 3.46 & 92.22 & 4.32 & 1.42 & 41.85 & 56.73 \\

17 & 3.56 & 91.88 & 4.56 & 1.41 & 41.90 & 56.68 \\

18 & 3.68 & 91.59 & 4.73 & 1.41 & 41.93 & 56.65 \\

19 & 3.80 & 91.38 & 4.82 & 1.41 & 41.94 & 56.65 \\

20 & 3.92 & 91.23 & 4.85 & 1.41 & 41.93 & 56.66   \\ 

\hline \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item[a] Results are expressed as a percent of variation.
    \item[b] The shock $\varepsilon_\tau$ represents the cumulative effects of shocks to the top marginal rate $\varepsilon_m$ and the capital gains rate $\varepsilon_c$.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable} 

\quad

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Variance Decomposition: 1964--2012$^a$}

\label{VarDecomp}

\begin{tabular}{c | D{.}{.}{1.2} D{.}{.}{2.2} D{.}{.}{1.2} | D{.}{.}{1.2} D{.}{.}{2.2} D{.}{.}{2.2} }

\hline \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Period} & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{Output Growth} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Deficit Ratio} \\
&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{${\varepsilon_\tau}^b$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\varepsilon_y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c |}{$\varepsilon_g$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{${\varepsilon_\tau}^b$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\varepsilon_y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\varepsilon_g$} \\ \hline

1 & 3.13 & 89.86 & 7.01 & 0.99 & 24.41 & 74.60 \\

2 & 2.04 & 88.74 & 9.22 & 1.05 & 29.32 & 69.63 \\

3 & 1.45 & 94.10 & 4.45 & 0.98 & 35.78 & 63.24 \\

4 & 1.64 & 98.15 & 0.21 & 0.98 & 39.97 & 59.06 \\

5 & 2.25 & 96.10 & 1.65 & 1.04 & 42.31 & 56.65 \\ \hline

6 & 2.92 & 89.87 & 7.21 & 1.16 & 43.50 & 55.34 \\

7 & 3.40 & 84.91 & 11.69 & 1.31 & 43.82 & 54.87 \\

8 & 3.64 & 84.18 & 12.18 & 1.46 & 43.52 & 55.02 \\

9 & 3.68 & 86.36 & 9.96 & 1.56 & 42.92 & 55.52 \\

10 & 3.60 & 89.09 & 7.30 & 1.61 & 42.31 & 56.08 \\ \hline

11 & 3.49 & 91.13 & 5.38 & 1.59 & 41.87 & 56.53 \\

12 & 3.39 & 92.28 & 4.33 & 1.55 & 41.65 & 56.80 \\

13 & 3.34 & 92.75 & 3.91 & 1.50 & 41.61 & 56.89 \\

14 & 3.34 & 92.78 & 3.88 & 1.46 & 41.67 & 56.87 \\

15 & 3.38 & 92.55 & 4.07 & 1.44 & 41.76 & 56.80 \\ \hline

16 & 3.46 & 92.22 & 4.32 & 1.42 & 41.85 & 56.73 \\

17 & 3.56 & 91.88 & 4.56 & 1.41 & 41.90 & 56.68 \\

18 & 3.68 & 91.59 & 4.73 & 1.41 & 41.93 & 56.65 \\

19 & 3.80 & 91.38 & 4.82 & 1.41 & 41.94 & 56.65 \\

20 & 3.92 & 91.23 & 4.85 & 1.41 & 41.93 & 56.66   \\ 

\hline \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item[a] Results are expressed as a percent of variation.
    \item[b] The shock $\varepsilon_\tau$ represents the cumulative effects of shocks to the top marginal rate $\varepsilon_m$ and the capital gains rate $\varepsilon_c$.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The problem is that the blank lines end the paragraphs.  See my answer below.  If you want to space things out use comment lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't end the paragraph between the tables.  Just put some horizontal space such as `\quad` to separate them, then they will stay together.  Here's a simple example

```
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Left}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Hello & There \\
This must be & a table \\
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\quad
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Right}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Hello & There \\
123 &  3545 \\
123 &  3545 \\
123 &  3545 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
```

which produces this

[image: a pic of the tables as produced by Latex]